# Laravel 4 (Beta 5) Routing error

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-4, composer-php

I decided to use a new framework to me for my new project so i started with Laravel!
I'm starting to like it, had few problems but it sorted out. But now i'm having hard times with Routing!

Using HomeController i get index page:

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` and everything is ok.

But i created new controller MeteoController using Artisan. And routing:

`Route::get('test', 'MeteoController@Attuale');` where controller is:

```
class MeteoController extends \BaseController {

public function Attuale()
{
    return View::make('meteo/meteoattuale');
}
```

}

Neither doesn't work with:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
   return View::make('meteoattuale');
});
```

Everytime calling /test i get 404.
I've googled and did: dump-autoload, even htaccess with mod_rewite.
Any ideas on what could cause this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a beta, you should be using beta projects for your mainstream releases

Comment: Is it Laravel's 404 error page or a page not found (Apache kind)?

Comment: Neither doesn't works if i try:
Route::get('test', function(){
    return View::make('meteoattuale');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in .htaccess and server configuration.

Problem solved by this post: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error)

And this one: [Epigroove.com](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the \ from BaseController.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything. When creating new controller Artisan by default add /

Comment: Yes, and non of them works. First i had page and controller names containing (-), so thought that cuold be the problem but nothing. Don't know is it Laravel or server. But from what i red Laravel is pretty stable now and most people is using it for thier projects.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem running L4 on WAMP (Windows 8). Solution that worked for me was:

-open apache httpd.conf and find

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite
```

-remove hashtag

-save httpd.conf

-restart WAMP

done!