# Laravel quick start guide route not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Ok, I'm new to Laravel so went straight to the documentation to get started. There are massive holes in the documentation so it took a lot of effort and googling to fill the gaps to get Laravel set up. I now have it set up and moved on to the next step in the quick start guide. I created my route

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
     return 'Users!';
});
```

Now it says:

```
Now, if you hit the /users route in your web browser, you should see Users!
```

So I hit up:

```
http://localhost/laravel/users
```

but get a 404? I tried

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/users
```

but still a 404? I followed the steps on the quick start guide to the letter, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you certain that laravel is there?  Can you access anything else in public?

Comment: yes I can access the welcome page 'you have arrived' default page, at this address http://localhost/laravel/public/

Comment: im running Ubuntu with Apache if that helps any, with mod rewrite turned on

Comment: What about localhost/laravel/public/index.php/users ?

Comment: It sounds like your htaccess/rewrite isn't working then.  Tripple check that you have mod rewrite turned on, and that you've got [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) configured correctly.  I would recommend that before too long you look in to virtual hosts too.

Comment: I really don't understand why LAravel has 450.000 downloads (!) but nobody except us has this problem! Laravel's tutorial is horrible, when you do it exactly like they same you'll run into exactly that error...

Comment: i had this problem and what i concluded is that the server hasn't got the mod-rewrite activated.

Comment: @PhillSparks can you help me with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653143/laravel-only-home-route-working) ? and explain the problem coz I'm new and want to understand the functionality of laravel

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Seems like your Laravel app is accesible via an Apache HTTP alias, because your URL looks like: `http://localhost/laravel/`. If this is the case *and assuming* that `http://localhost/laravel` is pointing to your public directory, then follow these steps:

1. Try to navigate to your expected route prepend it with `/index.php/`, in your case: `http://localhost/laravel/index.php/users`. If it works (no 404) then you problem is with the Rewrite Module configuration of Apache HTTP, you should follow the next steps.
2. Edit the file `public/.htaccess`.
3. Under the line `RewriteEngine On` add `RewriteBase /laravel/`.
4. Try to navigate to an existing route.

Basically, if you app resides in a alias or virtual directory (say `http://localhost/alias`) you should add an entry in your rewrite rule to rewrite the *base directory* with `alias`.

Comment: Hi Rubens, I think I'm getting close on this now. http://localhost/laravel/index.php/users dosn't work,but if I put public in the URL it does work like so http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/users

The rewritebase didn't work but im guessing I have to incorporate the /public directory into it somewhere?

Comment: Are you using WAMP? Then go to tray icon > click > Apache > Alias directories > Add an alias... then write an alias like `test` the set the directory as `C:\path\to\your\public\directory` then navigate to `http://localhost/test`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ended up having to create a virtual host.

Comment: This exact solution (`Rewritebase...`) worked on my Laravel installation under WAMP. My alias is `/localhost/laravel-demo/` Thx.

Comment: Be sure that `mod_rewrite` in `httpd.conf` is enabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16864142/1532882.

Comment: This was very helpful. I had the issue you described.

Comment: It works for laravel 4.2 + WAMP + alias points to public folder + custom port 7777. So what is the default RewriteBase if we don't specify it?

Comment: I needed to set `AllowOverride` to `all` for the directory the alias is in.

Comment: This is the exact solution. I tried a lot and find the solution at last. Thanks a lot

Comment: One could understand this solution also by looking at this [post](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/8df494eb-55a0-49ab-a45b-8ca37f6756ac)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is well explained by Rubens above, A simpler solution is to use the supplied built-in PHP Server by issuing this command

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

Note that I am using port 8080 here, you can omit it.Now you can browse the site by going to

```
localhost/users
```

and it should work!

Answer (score 3):

Apache isn't probably reading the public/.htaccess file due to the directive **AllowOverride** being set to **None**. Try to set it to **All**.

[Laravel 4 simple route not working using mod_rewrite, and .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772962/laravel-4-simple-route-not-working-using-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and spent hours to solve it. 
I have several apps under the same domain, but in different segments. So Laravel's url is `http://myhostname/mysubdir/`

My controllers were only working as `http://myhostname/mysubdir/index.php/mycontroller`

On /var/www/.../public/.htaccess I put `RewriteBase /mysubdir` and worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 4 years old but still it have its significance.Rubens Mariuzzo was answered it correctly but I want to add some points on it. You said

*"There are massive holes in the documentation so it took a lot of effort and googling to fill the gaps in order to get Laravel set-up"*

For beginners it is difficult to find correct way of configuring Laravel. Once it is mastered it is fun developing Laravel :) . There are certain correct way of doing this.

1. Download Laravel
2. Configure DB
3. Map DB in .env
4. Make auth: php artisan make:auth
5. Create model and migration together: php artisan make:model Todo -m
6. Migrate: php artisan migrate
7. Create controller and routes together: php artisan make:controller
   TodoController --resource
8. Create view for each action
9. Code the controller

Detailed description is given in this blog http://masterlaravel.blogspot.in/2017/08/laravelquick-start-composer-create.html

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this follow url and see RoboTamer's config:

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=511

it solved my problem the same as yours

solution in nginx:

server {

```
    server_name .laravel.dev;
    root /home/tamer/code/laravel/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    #browse folders if no index file
    autoindex on; 

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }


    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/lobby(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        include /home/tamer/code/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    access_log /home/tamer/code/laravel/storage/logs.access.log;
    error_log  /home/tamer/code/laravel/storage/logs.error.log;
```

}

Comment: Please summarize the answer here, in case the site goes offline.

Comment: Note: the linked article describes a solution for an installation under Nginx. Rubens answer is good for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Knowledge of the above by @rubens, and a comment by @GaryJ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error/16864142#16864142) made me do this to make it work from my Apache virtual hosts file.

Copied these lines from .htaccess file in laravel within  node of the vhosts config.
Removed my .htaccess file (it was anyway not being applied, i am on a windows apache virtual host, laravel env)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Better:
Later read @Ag0r0 's reply, that worked. i was missing the allow override, making the above neccessary. once allowoverride all was there, the default settings itself worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS & Apache 2.2`) I was stuck at #1 step of @Rubens' solution. I could see the page with this url: `http://localhost/laravel/index.php/users` but step #2 and others didn't work.

Also I've tried to add `RewriteBase /laravel/public` to `.htaccess` but it didn't work too.

Then I've set up a new virtual host with the help of this awesome tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts *(they rock with these tuts)*

In addition to tutorial, I've set `DocumentRoot` (in `example.com.conf` file) like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
```

Yes, `public` is the big deal here.

Btw, don't put `RewriteBase /laravel/` to your `.htacces` file otherwise you'll get `HTTP/500` error.

Now, I can see `example.com/users` page.

Answer (score -3):

my previous post with the describtion of the problem was deleted, but it was similar to the situation that is described here.

anyway... simply i have tried all the possibilities that are described here as well as on other pages and I did not find solution to my problem.

The fresh installation of the Laraval simply did not worked.... after trying everythink from this post i decided to create yet another fresh installation and miracle happened this installation is actually working...

So my advice is: if you are not able to fix this problem just try to create another installation of the laravel and it might actually work.

This might be actually the easiest way how to fix your problem in case you are starting from the scrach.