# Laravel 4 simple route not working using mod_rewrite, and .htaccess

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm not only new to Laravel 4, but new to using frameworks. I thought I'd start with Laravel since it's gotten such good reviews.
I've got a good install of Laravel. I go to /l4/public and see the welcome page.

I'm trying to add a route to routes.php so that when I navigate to /l4/public/articles I get a response.
I get "The requested URL /l4/public/articles was not found on this server." Do I need to run an artisan command to compile the routes? It's probably something easy. Why this message?

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('articles', function ()
{
    //return View::make('articles');
    return "Articles hello there";
});
```

Comment: have you got mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: No, I don't. Does Laravel expect that?

Comment: Why the hell does Laravel not say in its shitty tutorial that we need to activate mod_rewrite ????

Comment: @Panique welcome to the world of open source documentation.

Comment: This answer from delmadord save my life! http://stackoverflow.com/a/24785009/1419350

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Problem is solved by two editing changes in apache's httpd.conf file.

AllowOverride None is default. AllowOverride controls whether .htaccess files are processed.

mod_rewrite is commented out by default.

**Changes to make:**

Change 1: Activate mod_rewrite by uncommenting it.

Change 2:

Change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Now restart Apache...

The default .htaccess file that Laravel provides in the public folder specified some mod_rewrite rules. These rules were not getting applied because AllowOverride was set to none. Be sure and restart apache after changing these settings.
My configuration:  Apache 2.4.6 on Windows XP.

It appears that there may be some security implications to the AllowOverride change. If anyone has additional information on this, I would like to hear it.

Comment: I have all that enabled, and I still can't get the second route to work. "/" works, "index.php/articles" works, but not "articles".

Comment: Just to follow up. The only way it worked was to make a virtual host (instructions here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30053/getting-mod-rewrite-to-work-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I tried so many different things before falling onto this post. Great answer here, solved all my issues. Thanks for the great answer. Solution still working as of 7/28/2014

Answer (score 1):

That Error basically say that the router cannot found your request. Make sure you already save your changes.
if you using the artisan command to running the page,just re-run again command "artisan Serve".

Answer (score 0):

You need mod_rewrite on. Try: l4/public/index.php/articles

Comment: Yes, I tried l4/public/index.php/articles and it worked. Now I'm trying to understand why. I have Apache 2.4 with mod_rewrite commented out. phpinfo() does not show mod_rewrite loaded. Laravel does have it's default .htaccess file. Is URL rewriting happening anyway? Why can't I use the path l4/public/articles?

Comment: I've already said it, you need to activate mod_rewrite, make some research. Also make sure you have this htaccess https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess in you public folder

Answer (score 0):

in  httpd.conf change

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then uncomment

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```