# Laravel - Routes not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xampp

I'm learning Laravel ad routes not working i don;t know why .. there is three files ( `Welcome.blade.php` & `route.php` & `tryaction.php` ) , `tryaction` is a controller

in `Welcome.balde.php` :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ route('benice', ['action' => 'hug']) }}">Hug</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('benice', ['action' => 'kiss']) }}">Kiss</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('benice', ['action' => 'slap']) }}">Slap</a></li>
</ul>
```

in `route.php` :

```
Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', [
    'uses' => 'tryaction@doget',
    'as' => 'benice'
]);
```

in `tryaction.php` :

```
public function doget($action, $name = null){
    return view('actions.'.$action,['name'=>$name]);
}
```

why it's not working and gives me notFound exception ?

note:actions views ar located in a folder called actions inside views

**Now I tried something but still don't know the problem**

I created the app using composer inside a folder inside htdocs using xampp server, the hierarchy looks like:

```
├── htdocs
│   ├── laravelprojects
│   |   ├── myapp
```

when I moved myapp to htdocs directly it works .. why is that ?

Comment: Welcome.balde.php should be Welcome.blade.php

Comment: Can you show the entire error?

Comment: Do you have run default laravel welcome page? You must need to set apache rewrite engine and override enabled and given the permission to bootstrap, storage and define route in your routes.php

Comment: @CavidAliyev it's 'blade' .. I missed typing

Comment: @Jerodev 
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: @AfshanShujat yes I run on welcome page .. can you make it more clear ?

Comment: Where is your `route.php` file placed? Is it the `routes.php` file under `app\Http`, or are you using another routes file? Make sure you add the route file in the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: no it's default route file

Comment: Can you show the entire content of `tryaction.php`?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class tryaction extends Controller
{
    public function doget($action, $name = null){
   return view('actions.'.$action,['name'=>$name]);
  }
}
`

Comment: You need to check your apache configuration httpd.conf file for rewrite availability see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772962/laravel-4-simple-route-not-working-using-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

Comment: @AfshanShujat I checked it's already allowed on my server

Comment: I tried very basic routing like : `Route::get('/hug', function () {
    return 'hello from hug';
});` and it still not working ??!!

Comment: File name is 'routes.php' and it should be there in app/Http/routes.php. Can you checkout that you are using the same routes.php file to define your route.

Comment: @AfshanShujat checked it's default routes.php ... i didn't change any .. just added this new routes

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other .htaccess file in your directory that is not allowing rewriting if routes.

Answer (score 1):

**In versions of Laravel < 5.3:**

All routes live within the `app/Http/routes.php`

---

You need to make sure you are referencing the right file.

- Navigate to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider`
- Confirm that the appropriate file is being required.

  ```
  public function map(Router $router)
  {
      $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
          require app_path('Http/routes.php');
      });
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

You should read this:

[HTTP Routing - Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing)