# All routes throw NotFoundHttpException but home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, routes

I got this code in the routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
    return View::make('list.open');
}));

Route::get('room/{name}', array('as' => 'showRoom', 'uses' => 'RoomController@showRoom'));

Route::post('room', array('as' => 'openRoom', 'uses' => 'RoomController@openRoom'));
```

And this code in the RoomController.php:

```
class RoomController extends Controller {

    public function openRoom()
    {
      return "test";
    }

    public function showRoom($name)
    {
      return "test2";
    }
}
```

If I open public/ it will Show me the view list.open but if I open public/room/test it throw the NotFoundHttpException. (I also tried to use directly a function in the routes.php instead of the roomcontroller but it doesnt worked)

Can anyone help me?

Kind regards
Damon

Comment: Answer in this question may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16899065/1321384

Comment: ok, what webserver are you using on which operating system. And do you have any .htaccess?

Comment: XAMPP, Windows, yes, And if got 3 other laravel instances which are working (all installed from the same larapack zip). That's the only one which wont route anything but the home.

Comment: @yoma that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the public folder to your path, you can just go to `http://location.com/room/test`.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled a new larapack and deleted the old one... I've to start from Zero but now it works.