# Laravel - only home route working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-artisan

**the problem**
all routes are typed correctly and checked by php artisan route:list here the output

```
+--------+----------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------
-------+------------+
|←[32m Domain ←[39m|←[32m Method   ←[39m|←[32m URI  ←[39m|←[32m Name   ←[39m|←[3
2m Action                                           ←[39m|←[32m Middleware ←[39m
|
+--------+----------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------
-------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /    | home   | App\Http\Controllers\QuoteController@getIn
dex    | web        |
|        | POST     | new  | create | App\Http\Controllers\QuoteController@addNe
wQuote | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | test | test   | App\Http\Controllers\QuoteController@getTe
st     | web        |
+--------+----------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------
-------+------------+
```

only root route is working nothing else

**what I tried:**

- create another route and I made sure that no routes are working only
  home route, still not working except `home`
- tried to change OverrideMode from None to All, didn't fix any
- tried to type manually `localhost/quotes/public/index.php` BOOM it works ..

**my htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**working on:**

- Windows 10
- XAMP

Comment: From the laravel docs "Once you have assigned a name to a given route, you may use the route's name when generating URLs or redirects via the global `route` function." I think this means you're missing a `Route::post("create"...` in your routes.php.

Comment: What you wants to do is form not submitting?? or you have problem with views?

Comment: @apokryfos in `route.php` what about the second route ?? is that what you r talking about?

Comment: @BindeshPandya I'm just testing if route of form is working.. it gives me route not found when I click submit button

Comment: Nevermind, I missed the "as" part in the routes. Can you inspect the rendered document source to make sure the URL is valid (i.e. not escaped or something)?

Comment: please clear more,what you want exactly

Comment: @ImtiazPabel is there a way to refresh routes with composer or artisan ?

Comment: To refresh the cached routes, use `php artisan route:clear`. If you want to see all your routes to see if they are being registered properly, you can use `php artisan route:list`. Hope this helps. You should really be more clear about what errors you are getting and what you expect in the question!

Comment: Try `action="{!! route('create') !!}"` to make sure the URL is not escaped.

Comment: didn't work for me .. can  you tell me what what's the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!} ?

Comment: @PhillSparks can I get some help here ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all write your form like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'QuoteController@store')) !!}
                <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="author-form">Author Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="author-form" id="author-form" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="quote-form">Quote:</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="quote-form" id="quote-form" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><button type="submit">Add Quote</button></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
    </table>
                {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Now for routing part, if you use laravel 5.2 you need to assign web middleware in route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::resource('quate', 'QuoteController');

});
```

Finally your QuoteController create store method in it, if you created controller with artisan command it will automatic generate all required methods

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;


class QuoteController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){

        return view('welcome');
    }
    public function create(){
        return view('test');
    }
public function store(Request $request){
       // Some Code here
    }
}
```

now when you write **quate** in url it opens welcome view and when you write create it opens the test view and this is working code in my local.

Comment: There is no `Form::` in Laravel 5.x

Comment: Also, you don't need the web middleware anymore - this is now handled in the routing service provider.

Comment: @Pyton there is no `Form::` in the default Laravel installation. You can still add it as a dependency via composer. I think the idea was to make Laravel more modular and let the developer choose additional modules if they need them.

Comment: I know it, but author could not.