# Why is my route in Laravel returning a 404 error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So in my routes.php file I have this:

```
Route::get('contact', function() {
   return view('contact');
});
```

When I go to domain.com/contact I get a return error. However when I put:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('contact');
});
```

and go to domain.com the page appears. Any idea what could be causing this?

Full Routes file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('homeIndex');
});

Route::get('contact', function() {
    return view('contact');
});
```

php artisan route:list returns:

```
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI     | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /       |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | contact |      | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: can you share more codes of your routes.php? maybe all the routes in it? this could be due to having route group with prefix on top of the route you are having error

Comment: It is the first route I'm trying to get to work, but I posted it as I have it.

Comment: try to add a "/" in front ur contact route... `Route::get('/contact', function....`

Comment: @TommyLee That didn't work, I also tried 'contact/' and '/contact/'

Comment: is this on ur local development or a production server?

Comment: @Nash please try this command `php artisan routes` or `php artisan route:list` and see if your route is there !

Comment: `php artisan route:list` if u are using laravel ver >5

Comment: +--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
    | Domain | Method   | URI     | Name | Action  | Middleware |
    +--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /       |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | contact |      | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+

Comment: Better to paste it somewhere like http://kopy.io

Comment: That's really weird ! Please try to clear the cache `artisan route:clear` who knows !

Comment: Show us the error log `laravel/storage/logs`.

Comment: @azeós there is no error in the log for this. It is just going to 404 and not returning any kind of error.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I cleared the route cache and I"m getting the same result

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` or your server ?

Comment: I will note that I went to /index.php/contact and it worked... I don't know why it would do that, but it is

Comment: @Nash if that worked then you are using either `Apache/Nginx` and you need to check your `.htaccess/location`  !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel quick start guide route not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897504/laravel-quick-start-guide-route-not-working)

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I found the answer, my mod_rewrite wasn't enabled. As soon as I did that on apache everything works fine. Thanks for taking your time to trya nd help me.

Comment: @Nash that was my next guess ;) good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I fixed my issue. If anyone else has this issue make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server. You do this by going to the terminal and entering

`a2enmod rewrite`

then typing

`service apache2 restart`

It now works like a charm.