# Laravel page redirecting showing 404 error

Tags: laravel

web.php route is

```
Route::get('/profile', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class,'profile'])->name('profile');
```

In HomeController function

```
public function profile()
    {      
      return view('profile');
    }
```

And also profile.blade.php file exist. When try to loading http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile link returns 404 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my route in Laravel returning a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733180/why-is-my-route-in-laravel-returning-a-404-error)

Comment: i have checked with php artisan route:list this command my route(profile) not showing in list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878951/how-to-clear-route-caching-on-server-laravel-5-2-37

Comment: i have tried this php artisan route:cache command now route showing.

Comment: Ok, so try the link in the first comment if error still exists