# .htaccess setting: Laravel Page redirect is not working

Tags: php, apache, laravel, web, laravel-5

Here's is My Laravel-5.4 code that i am facing problem. I had created test laravel project with two pages **home** & **about us** and mapped the file path using Apache v-host(www.test.com)
  When i hit ***www.test.com*** it loads correctly to the index page but when i try to hit ***www.test.com/about*** It showing 404 error .But when i hit like this url  ***www.test.com/index.php/about*** page loads properly
I don't know its problem is in my code or Apache configuration or any other

**controller:**

```
public function index(){
    return view('pages.index');
}
public function about(){
    return view('pages.about');
}
```

**Route :**

```
// Home Page
Route::get('/','pagesController@index');
// About Us Page
Route::get('/about','pagesController@about');
```

**Apache conf:**

```
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName test.com
   ServerAlias www.test.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public/
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: could you share the `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory?

Comment: @BagusTesa my .htaccess 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Comment: Please add it to your question..

Comment: @HarishKarthick : Please edit your question with this details! (i.e. .htaccess)

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur ok

Comment: could you check in `php.ini`, to make sure `mod_rewrite` is active.

Comment: You have to configure things so it works with public_html instead of public

Comment: @HarishKarthick: I think you should follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897504/laravel-quick-start-guide-route-not-working) more help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have an issue with mod_rewrite that is not enabled.

Try to enable it with `a2enmod rewrite` and then restart apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Give a look to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/5018815).

**OR**

If it's not working. 
This may come from Apache conf : `etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. 
This [article](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working) will explain it better than me.

You may need to edit :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

And restart apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

**OR**

If it's still not working try to do some `chmod 0755` on your Laravel's project.

Comment: I have added another possible solution. Hope this will work.

Comment: Glad to have helped you !  Don't forget to validate the answer ;)

Comment: Sure Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Do you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled on apache?
In order to use `mod_rewrite` you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

This is the `.htaccess` I have on my `public/` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also, editing `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I rewrite  and restarted apache still iam facing the problem

Comment: @HarishKarthick Have you added `AllowOverride all` in <Directory>??

Comment: After **AllowOverride all** in directory it works perfectly Thanks Bro it works! thanks a lot

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it works! So that other user may have get right solution!

Comment: I have 11 reputation 15 is needed sorry but once again thanks u lot