# Laravel 5 - Internal Pages giving Not Found Error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

Actually I am deploying my **laravel 5** Application on **Linode Server**.
My client create space for me in such type of path.

```
var/www/html/abcproject
```

I point out my godaddy domain to abcproject directory.

Now I have uploaded my all **Laravel 5** files on **abcproject** directory.

My issue is that , my home page is working fine but my internal pages
are giving Not Fount Error.

Suppose when I try to logged in it is giving below error.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /abcproject/login was not found on this server.
```

Secondly Laravel 5 URL is getting url like that.

Supposed URL.
http://15.30.19.61/abcproject/index.php/registers

I did not understand where is and what is the issue.

One thing is my project is working fine when I try such type of URL.

`http://example.com/index.php/`  But In this case my URL Rewriting did not work but project is working like I can logged in, go in different pages, Logout etc.

**My HTACCESS FILE**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: you should point your domain on "var/www/html/abcproject/public" directory instead of  "var/www/html/abcproject" directory.

Comment: could be a .htacces problem aswell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 4 all routes except home result in 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error)

Comment: Enable mod rewrite on Apache2.

Comment: mod rewrite module is active

Comment: @Deathstorm how to solve from htaccess file ??

Comment: could you show your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have shown my htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering your laravel project from a sub folder such as you mentioned above:

> http://15.30.19.61/abcproject

You should add this to your .htaccess file under **RewriteEngine On**.

```
RewriteBase /abcproject
```

Comment: Second I have created two .htaccess file - 1. on root and 2. on public folder. So on which i need to change ? both or on public htaccess file

Comment: Where is ur index.php located? Root or public?

Comment: On root - I was renamed server.php file to index.php

Comment: In the case such as urs what I usually do is move the index.php and .htaccess files from the public directory into the root directory. Then I modify the index.php file and change the bootstrap includes from /../bootstrap to /bootstrap and then add RewriteBase /projectName to .htaccess and then laravel works on sub folders in apache

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue with LAMP configuration and I resolved by enabling rewrite rules of apache. If some needs details then it can be referred at the below blog notes
http://ankgne.com/post/setting-up-digital-ocean-for-laravel-application

- Step 1: Enabling mod re-write using sudo a2enmod rewrite
- Step 2: Allowing the laravel .htaccess (in public directory of laravel page)
  file to apply rewrite rules

  ```
   sudo vi  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
  ```

  and adding below lines

  **Note**: Change "/var/www/html" to "path of laravel public folder"

```
  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  

  . . .
```

Step 3: Restarting web server using

```
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```