# Lumen API routes not working. Only 'public/' route works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, lumen

I've installed Lumen and created a new project using de composer.
I have de project folder under my Apache24/htdocs folder (I'm using Windows 10).

The 'localhost/myapp/public/' works fine. The problem appears when I create a new route, say '/test' return some string:

```
$app->get('/test', function () use ($app) {
return 'test'; });
```

Then, when I try 'localhost/myapp/public/test' I get a 404 error.

My htaccess is the default that comes with the project created:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

My Apache config has the AllowOverride All 
and the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is enabled.

The suggestions in [laravel 4 all routes except home result in 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error) were tried, but none of that solved the problem for me...

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteBase /myapp/public`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mike.
I added RewriteBase /myapp/public to my .htaccess and then it worked.