# How can this problem be solved -> Laravel Route 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.7

I have just installed laravel 5.7. So, In web.php I have defined Route.. Like

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

But when i Hit the URL -> http://localhost/rp/public/foo

It shows me 404 page not found.

Comment: Your URL should be `http://localhost/rp/foo`, if `.htaccess` is setup correctly. By default in Laravel, you shouldn't have to have `public` in your URL.

Comment: @MhDip You should look at [laravel showing 404 for routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error).

Comment: how about this url `http://localhost/foo`

Comment: No solution have not worked for me. i set up public directory files in a root directory and i have also set up properly .htaccess file. Yet it gives me same error.. now my URL look like Route::get('/admin',function(){ return "Welcome Admin" });

Answer (score 1):

use PHP's built-in development server, you may use the  serve Artisan command:`php artisan serve`

Later you can check in browser like this: http://localhost:8000/foo

---

If you have to check without artisan serve

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

you can check like this(rp is your laravel-project-name): http://localhost/rp/public/foo

you must have a configuration like this in your [.htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) file

Comment: This ain't the solution though.

Comment: No solution have not worked for me. i set up public directory files in a root directory and i have also set up properly .htaccess file. Yet it gives me same error..  now my URL look like

Route::get('/admin',function(){
    return "Welcome Admin"
});

Comment: @MhDip Then there will be some problems with your other code, can you please show me the full code of your `routes/web.php`

Comment: my local directory name is rp.. somehow . i have solved this problem.. but...
when write code like 
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return "admin";
});

it redirect to .. 404 page 

but when i write code like 

Route::get('rp/admin', function () {
    return "admin";
});
it shows the expected result.. but i don't want to define the root directory .. rp/admin.. like thatt

Comment: see the comment  bro @UdhavSarvaiya. mistakenly i press enter before finish the content :(

Comment: I'm glad you got the solution @MhDip what is the reason behind your case I don't know but I check my code in my pc and its working properly, you not required project name [check this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/routes/web.php#L14) and [check this also](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing) [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)