# Laravel Custom Controller getting 404 error

Tags: php, laravel

I have created the new controller using command line on laravel

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

just display the string on a function of PhotoController like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PhotoController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        echo 'Dev';
    }
```

Called the controller on route web.php

```
Route::get('photos', 'PhotoController@getName');
```

When i trying to load the url of controller

```
http://localhost/dev_laravel/public/photos
```

getting 404 Not found error

I also tried

```
http://localhost/dev_laravel/public/photo/
http://localhost/dev_laravel/public/photo/getname/
```

I'm beginner or learner for laravel and working on 5.8 version

php artisan route:list

after

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How you run laravel  ? `php artisan serve` ? try `http://localhost/photos`

Comment: Is this related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error ?

Comment: where is your project directory?

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @ZahidHassanShaikot on localhost

Comment: remove echo and write return "dev";

Comment: @GovindChinnasamy: reply on my previous comment ?

Comment: @vivek_23 i checked those too. can i achieve without configure the site on vitual host?

Comment: you have somewhere `echo 'test';` check that line

Comment: sorry echo replaced with "return" now. route:list showing the controller on Action column

Comment: are you running your project , on which port. ? 

if you run php artisan serve by default it runs on 8000  port ( if the port is free ) and it should be accessible by http://localhost:8000/

Comment: @NikleshRaut I tried but nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal
and Run This Command

```
php artisan serve
```

Open Second Terminal and run this command

```
php artisan route:list
```

And then Your url pattern is like

`http://localhost:8000/photos`
or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos
```

Comment: This should be working, but OP is not replying, how he is running local server ?

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan serve
```

it gives a link like http://127.0.0.1:8000/ or your desire port if you set a port for it then just add photos like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos
```