# How to pass ID from url to controller in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, url

I want my view page to open when the type the url as www.domain-name.in/sample/ID. ID can be an integer valure of 5 digits. Right now my view page is opening when I type the url as www.domain-name.in/sample but when i type www.domain-name.in/sample/ID, I'm getting 404 error. 
This is my route :

```html
Route::get('/{$id}','HomeController@index');
```

This is my controller

```html
public function index(Request $request,$id)
    {
        return view('filename');
    }
```

How can I get view page with this url : www.domain-name.in/sample/ID

Comment: Please show your route `web.php`.

Comment: Route::get('/{$id}','HomeController@index');

Comment: Have you added route prefix then I have updated my answer try it

Comment: Please remove the `$` sign in your route. No need to use `$`.
`Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, any Laravel route that you defined gives a 404 here and if that is the case, see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-do-i-always-get-a-404-error-for-any-route-i-create and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error

Comment: Also, route such as `/{$id}` is bad as it could match any other route as well. You better put that under some route group which has a prefix or have some fixed URI at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Your **route** will be

```
Route::get('sample/{id}','HomeController@index')->where(['id' => '[0-9]{1,5}');
```

Your **controller** will be

```
public function index($id)
{
   echo $id;
   exit;
   return view('filename');
}
```

Now you can access it as url as below.

```
www.domain-name.in/sample/12345
```

**"12345"** is integer value of 5 digits sample id.

Comment: Can you tell me what URL are you execute on the browser?

Comment: Thank u. Route::get('/{id}','HomeController@index')->where(['id' => '[0-9]{1,5}'); Removed sample from route.

Comment: You need to add `sample/11244` in route. Consider it as true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below code:

If you defined route group in `web.php` then use:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sample'], function(){
    Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

And in the controller:

```
public function index(Request $request,$id)
{
    $myid = $id;
    return view('filename', compact('myid'));
}
```