# Route not working on laravel 7 except default one

Tags: php, routes, laravel-7

I have installed a fresh copy of laravel 7.0 today and I am working with following routes and controllers

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/','DashboardController@dashboard');
Route::get('dashboard2','DashboardController@dashboard2');
Route::get('dashboard3','DashboardController@dashboard3');
```

**DashboardController**

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard(){
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }

    public function dashboard2(){
        return view('dashboard.index2');
    }

    public function dashboard3(){
        return view('dashboard.index3');
    }
}
```

All of these routes returns 404 not found except these one `Route::get('/','DashboardController@dashboard');` 
Here I have discovered that the route having `'/'` url only works fine because if I change `dashboard2` url to `'/'` it also works,

other routes are also working on Laravel Development server by `php  artisan serve` command. But I am not used to do so, Is there any solution?

**route list**

```
+--------+----------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------
---+
|        | GET|HEAD |            |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@dashboard  | web
   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard2 |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@dashboard2 | web
   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard3 |      | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@dashboard3 | web
   |
+--------+----------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------
---+
```

> I already cleared all caches like route, view, config etc

Comment: Have you tried adding a / to your routes e.g. Route::get('/dashboard2', 'DashboardController@dashboard2')

Comment: yes I already tried that

Comment: Please show the result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Your `.env` urls are all correct?

Comment: Show the structure of your views folder

Comment: `.env` remains as default, only edited DB, user, password

Comment: Is the htaccess file present in your public/ folder? Also could you provide the confines to your apache/nginx/...

Comment: Is your `APP_URL` variable in `.env` correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4 All Routes Except Home Result in 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error)

Comment: structure of view `views>dashboard>index2...` @iJamesPHP2

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error, you need to enable the rewrite module

Comment: @RobinGillitzer APP_URL doesn't have any effect on this

Comment: I have no issue with .htaccess as it remains just same as laravel default

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864142/12872923

Comment: I already tried those before asking @RobinGillitzer

Comment: I am using laragon and I found the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` on `httpd.conf` is already uncommented

Answer (score 1):

Just update your composer. 100% work even in CPANEL mode.

Answer (score 0):

add to your .htaccess RewriteBase / and copy this file to root, this solved my problems on a clean install WAMP+laravel 7